# JQuery: triggering event when keypress problem

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, live

I have in trouble to trigger a click event when enter key is pressed.
When I use below codes, the live('click') event is triggered 3 times (which means the alert message is shown 3 thmes) when I press an enter key. Thanks in advance!! - KS from Korea

```
$('.searchWord').live('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {  
 $('.bBtnSearchBoard').trigger('click');
    }
});

$('.bBtnSearchBoard').live('click', function() {
 alert('a');

});
```

Comment: @ks park , cambraca is suggesting to check if you have multiple divs with the same class name

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you either have multiple `.searchWord` elements nested within each other, or, you have multiple `.bBtnSearchBoard` elements.

Answer (score 0):

try keydown

```
$('.searchWord').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {  
 $('.bBtnSearchBoard').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. I tried the 'keydown' but I got the same result.

Comment: @ks Park did you check for multiple classes names inside your html , do a search on "searchWord" and "bBtnSearchboard"

Comment: But I found the reason just before why I get the result. I use Jquery UI Tabs (3 tabs) and there is a button which has ".bBtnSearchBoard" class in each tab. I should have specifyed directly the button I wanted to be clicked. I solved by using function() call not using a triggering. Thanks gov.

Comment: ^^ gov, you are right. you pointed the right thing while I write my comment. Cheers!!

Comment: @ks Park , thats nice you fixed the problem , you can give +1 ...for my answer...hmmm

Comment: there up and down arrow right above zero , if you click up its like saying answer is good, if you click down that means you are saying answer is bad.

Comment: Sorry gov, there needs some reputations to vote up. but this is my first question and I have no reputation enough to vote. ^^

Comment: When I got it enough, I will vote it up. Cheers. KS from Korea

Comment: @ks Park , no problem , this site is simply superb , i joined only 2 months back but learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine on [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/DjASs/). Maybe your problem is that `.bBtnSearchBoard` returns more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.searchWord').live('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {  
 $('.bBtnSearchBoard').click();
    }
});

$('.bBtnSearchBoard').live('click', function() {
  //do your stuff here
 $(this).die("click"); //The first time this method executes unbinds the click handler from matched elements
 return false; //to prevent bubbling up of this event higher up the DOM
});
```